# One Combobox, One Button, & Two pages in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

this is a revised post about the same question. Using tkinter, i want to add a button to a frame (FrameFour) that opens up a page when a certain value is selected in a Combobox. For instance, if 1 is selected and the button is clicked, then frameOne should open, if two is selected and the button clicked, then frameTwo should open. The code i have for  FrameFour is as below

```
class PageFour(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    self.InitUI()

def nextButton(self,controller):
    if self.mychoice.get()=='1':
        controller.show_frame(PageTwo)

def InitUI(self):
    self.mychoice=StringVar()

    self.combo = ttk.Combobox(self,width =15, textvariable=self.mychoice)
    self.combo['values']=(" ","1","2")
    self.combo.grid(column=1, row=0)
    self.label=ttk.Label(self, text="How many files do you want to Process?")
    self.label.grid(column=0, row=0)


    self.button=ttk.Button(self, text="Next",command=self.nextButton)
    self.button.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

app = GUI_ATT()
app.mainloop()

but now i get the error message "TypeError: nextButton() missing 1 required positional argument: 'controller'" when i run the code. All the other pages work well and link to each other correctly. 
Pls let me know if you require more information.

Cheers

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Hi @ReblochonMasque. Thanks for your response, the post has been revised. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the Button and the command, you don't need to make that again. Try this:

```
class PageFour(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.InitUI()

    def nextButton(self):
        if self.mychoice.get()=='1':
            self.controller.show_frame(PageTwo)

    def InitUI(self):
        self.mychoice=StringVar()

        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(self,width =15, textvariable=self.mychoice)
        self.combo['values']=(" ","1","2")
        self.combo.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.label=ttk.Label(self, text="How many files do you want to Process?")
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0)


        self.button=ttk.Button(self, text="Next",command=self.nextButton)
        self.button.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response @Novel . It still doesn't work however. I've revised the post with updates now anyway. Cheers

Comment: @ConstantLearner I edited my answer to show you how to resolve the error. FWIW that's a very basic error you should be able to solve without help. I suggest you go back to basics and run through a couple python beginner's tutorials. Maybe try a beginner's forum like learnpython.reddit.com for help.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Many thanks indeed. Still very much a newbie and i must have jumped ahead of myself in my learning process :-) . Will definitely check out the beginners forum referenced.